# How does one hide the bottom UI bar?

Tags: starcraft-2

An example of what I'm talking about was seen during the large Roach-Hydra battle in the game between DIMAGA and JulyZerg as part of the GSL World Championship Team League.

Under what circumstances can you use this?

Comment: I noticed that too; it's clearly something built into the game but I haven't seen anything about how to engage it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try pressing Ctrl+W while observing a match. No clue if this will work when playing as it is mostly an observing/replay feature (and I can't test it right now).

Comment: It doesn't appear to work while playing (not that you'd need it to).